# Error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int*'

Tags: c++

I am trying to add an element to a Dualy Linked List in C++. I am stuck an error telling my it cannot convert from int to int*. Here is the code that the error occurs at:

```
void DLList::addNode(int data, int priority) {
    node *n;
    n = new node;
    n->priority = priority;
    n->data = data;
    if (DLList::first == NULL)
        DLList::first = n;
    else
        DLList::last = n;
}
```

The values data and priority are both integer values that are selected through a random number generator in the main function and are used to call the `addNode` function. The error does occur at the line

```
    n->data = data;
```

Here is the struct for the node:

```
struct node {
int priority;
int *data;
node *next;
node *prev;
};
```

Comment: Wild guess: at least one of `node::data` and `node::priority` was declared as a pointer. In the future, please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you show the code for the type `node`?

Comment: You need to point out which line has the error. The definition of `node` is also important. Have you considered the possibility that you are using an `int` in a place that expects an `int*`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `data` is the only `int` in your example, I will go ahead and assume that the error is on this line

```
n->data = data;
```

So your `node` struct has something like this in it:

```
struct node
{
 //Nodey stuff
 int* data;
};
```

Thus, `n->data = data;` makes no sense. You meant to do `*(n->data) = data;`.

EDIT : As T.C. points out in the comments, this solution assumes that you have indeed allocated space for `node::data`. A cleaner solution is to make `node::data` an `int` like this:

```
struct node {
int priority;
int data;
node *next;
node *prev;
};
```

Now, you don't need to change `DLList::addNode`. `n->data = data` will work fine.

Comment: I just edited with the full struct and confirming where the error occurs

Comment: Given the code in the OP, `*(n->data) = data;` won't work. Either `data` should be an `int` and not an `int *`, or another `new` is needed to allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I feel kind of dumb now for missing it! Thank you for all who commented. The issue was the fact that the data was declared as `int *data` I removed the * from data and the code now works! Thank you all for your responses, I appologise for the dumb problem...